# Making a regex to accept different conditions of the same line

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex

I'm working on a assignment that demands to write a java program that does equivalent of sql operations without using advanced libraries.so it will read line after line of operations from inputOps.sql for example .

```
CREATE TABLE student(id:integer, gpa:decimal, name:string, family:string,isMale:Boolean) 
INSERT INTO student(id,gpa,name,family,isMale) VALUES (50,null,”Ali”, “Hasani”, true)
SELECT id, name FROM student WHERE id=0
```

then the program will analyze each of this lines ;checking for any inconsistencies or errors.then the line's operation will be executed and finally a log will be generated in a file like log.txt.

```
ERROR: Duplicate column name 
family Table student created
ERROR: Table student already exists 
ERROR: Invalid table name st
```

there will be third file that functions as the database .I've chosen JSON format for this task so operations such as create and insert will save an JSON array in the JSON file.

```
["student",["23","3.5","john","johnson","true"]]
```

one of the things about insert operation is that user doesn't have to mention every data column(id,gpa...) so if users operation line is :

```
INSERT INTO student(id,name,family,isMale) VALUES (10,”diane”, “derringer”, false)
```

program will understand that users has not specified a value for gpa and will automatically assign null as it's value for the JSON array that will be created for the insert operation.
for parsing the input line I'm using regular expression so be using this code to parse the line:

```
Pattern insertPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(INSERT)(INTO)(\\w+)(\\()(\\w+)(,)(\\w+)(,)(\\w+)(,)(\\w+)(,)(\\w+)(\\))(VALUES)(\\()(\\d+|null )(,)(\\d+|null)(,)(\\w+|null)(,)(\\w+|null)(,)(\\w+)(\\))(.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = insertPattern.matcher(inputLine);
```

then by using matcher.group() I would make 2 arrays ;typeArray for the (id,name etc)part,and valueArray for the values.
then program would check each object of typeArray to match it with one of data types(name,gpa) and then make the valid JSON Array for the inserted row.

and here is the problem.the pattern I use only matches the line with all of the types mentioned ,and only solution that comes in my mind is to make different patterns for different kind of lines(one for line with 3 types mentioned ,one for 4 and so on) which doesn't seem smart and also should be problematic when I want to make methods to categorize it's errors.

What should I do for this problem ?
Is there any way to make regex to accept different conditions ?

p.s:I'm quite new to programming .

Comment: this is **not** a appropriate problem for a regular expression alone, there is a reason that Java has `if/else if/else` constructs.

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."* — Jamie Zawinski

Comment: "only solution that comes in my mind is to make different patterns for different kind of lines(one for line with 3 types mentioned ,one for 4 and so on)"

so you think that's the solution ?

Comment: parsing can be done completely without regular expressions, things like `ANTLR` and its predecessors exist for a reason. **This is off-topic for many reasons, too-broad being a primary one.**

Comment: *does sql operations without sql* what does that even mean? I think you have been asked to write a SQL parser and validator. Regex is not what you are being asked to do and if this is what you are being asked to do and regex is your first thought you have already failed. But like I said, this makes no sense, so guessing is useless.

Comment: This is what the assignment is . my point was that assignment wants the student to write a data management program like sql .and I've just started to learn programming .

Comment: then you also have failed at writing your question, and it is **completely off-topic** with this clarification!